# Arduino radio frequency receiver does not work with motor shield

Tags: c++, c, arduino, robotics

Micro-controller : SainSmart Mega 2560
Motor Shield: Osepp Motor Shield  V1.0
I am trying to implement Radio Frequency communication on my wheeled robot however when the motors are running the radio frequency code will not receive messages.

The motor shield uses pins 4,7,8,12
I have setup the radio frequency to occur on pins 22,23 ,5

I see this reference to 
[Why does VirtualWire conflicts with PWM signal in Arduino/ATmega328 pin D10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21069867/why-does-virtualwire-conflicts-with-pwm-signal-in-arduino-atmega328-pin-d10)
but am not sure if this applies to my situation.

**How do I get Radio Frequency receiver/transmitter to work while motor shield in use?**

code demonstrating the situation:

```
  #include <RH_ASK.h>
  #include <SPI.h> // Not actually used but needed to compile
  RH_ASK driver(2000, 22, 23, 5,true); // ESP8266: do not use pin 11
  /// *************************
  //      MOTOR SETUP
  /// *************************
  // Arduino pins for the shift register
  #define MOTORLATCH 12
  #define MOTORCLK 4
  #define MOTORENABLE 7
  #define MOTORDATA 8

  // 8-bit bus after the 74HC595 shift register
  // (not Arduino pins)
  // These are used to set the direction of the bridge driver.
  #define MOTOR1_A 2
  #define MOTOR1_B 3
  #define MOTOR2_A 1
  #define MOTOR2_B 4
  #define MOTOR3_A 5
  #define MOTOR3_B 7
  #define MOTOR4_A 0
  #define MOTOR4_B 6

    // Arduino pins for the PWM signals.
    #define MOTOR1_PWM 11
    #define MOTOR2_PWM 3
    #define MOTOR3_PWM 6
    #define MOTOR4_PWM 5
    #define SERVO1_PWM 10
    #define SERVO2_PWM 9

    // Codes for the motor function.
    #define FORWARD 1
    #define BACKWARD 2
    #define BRAKE 3
    #define RELEASE 4

    void setup()
    {
        Serial.begin(9600); // Debugging only
        if (!driver.init())
             Serial.println("init failed");

      //comment out code below  to allow receiver to read radio frequency  communication
      //BEGIN
        motor(1, FORWARD, 255);
        motor(2, FORWARD, 255);
        motor(4, FORWARD, 255);
        motor(3, FORWARD, 255);
       //END

    }
    void loop()
    {
        uint8_t buf[RH_ASK_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
        uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);
        if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) // Non-blocking
        {
            int i=0;
            // Message with a good checksum received, dump it.
            driver.printBuffer("Got:", buf, buflen);
            buf[5]= '\0';
            Serial.println((char*)buf);
        }
    }


    void motor(int nMotor, int command, int speed)
    {
      int motorA, motorB;

      if (nMotor >= 1 && nMotor <= 4)
      {  
        switch (nMotor)
        {
        case 1:
          motorA   = MOTOR1_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR1_B;
          break;
        case 2:
          motorA   = MOTOR2_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR2_B;
          break;
        case 3:
          motorA   = MOTOR3_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR3_B;
          break;
        case 4:
          motorA   = MOTOR4_A;
          motorB   = MOTOR4_B;
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }

        switch (command)
        {
        case FORWARD:
          motor_output (motorA, HIGH, speed);
          motor_output (motorB, LOW, -1);     // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        case BACKWARD:
          motor_output (motorA, LOW, speed);
          motor_output (motorB, HIGH, -1);    // -1: no PWM set
          break;;
        case RELEASE:
          motor_output (motorA, LOW, 0);  // 0: output floating.
          motor_output (motorB, LOW, -1); // -1: no PWM set
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
      }
    }

    void motor_output (int output, int high_low, int speed)
    {
      int motorPWM;

      switch (output)
      {
      case MOTOR1_A:
      case MOTOR1_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR1_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR2_A:
      case MOTOR2_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR2_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR3_A:
      case MOTOR3_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR3_PWM;
        break;
      case MOTOR4_A:
      case MOTOR4_B:
        motorPWM = MOTOR4_PWM;
        break;
      default:
        speed = -3333;
        break;
      }

      if (speed != -3333)
      {
        shiftWrite(output, high_low);
        if (speed >= 0 && speed <= 255)    
        {
          analogWrite(motorPWM, speed);
        }
      }
    }

    void shiftWrite(int output, int high_low)
    {
      static int latch_copy;
      static int shift_register_initialized = false;
      if (!shift_register_initialized)
      {
        // Set pins for shift register to output
        pinMode(MOTORLATCH, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORENABLE, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORDATA, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(MOTORCLK, OUTPUT);

        // Set pins for shift register to default value (low);
        digitalWrite(MOTORDATA, LOW);
        digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, LOW);
        digitalWrite(MOTORCLK, LOW);
        // Enable the shift register, set Enable pin Low.
        digitalWrite(MOTORENABLE, LOW);
        // start with all outputs (of the shift register) low
        latch_copy = 0;
        shift_register_initialized = true;
      }
      bitWrite(latch_copy, output, high_low);
      shiftOut(MOTORDATA, MOTORCLK, MSBFIRST, latch_copy);
      delayMicroseconds(5);    // For safety, not really needed.
      digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(5);    // For safety, not really needed.
      digitalWrite(MOTORLATCH, LOW);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the reference you give could be the problem. To try that fix just find the RH_ASK.cpp file and uncomment line 16 like this

```
// RH_ASK on Arduino uses Timer 1 to generate interrupts 8 times per bit interval
// Define RH_ASK_ARDUINO_USE_TIMER2 if you want to use Timer 2 instead of Timer 1 on Arduino
// You may need this to work around other libraries that insist on using timer 1
#define RH_ASK_ARDUINO_USE_TIMER2
```

Comment: when I make that change the RF components stop communicating. I must have something else using timer 2

Answer (score 0):

Your motor is using pin 5:

> #define MOTOR4_PWM 5

Try using a different third pin for your radio (make sure to match your software and hardware to the same new pin). Glancing at [the specsheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2549-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega640-1280-1281-2560-2561_datasheet.pdf), one option would be pin 24. Your motor code reserves every pin from 0 through 12. So, try...

> RH_ASK driver(2000, 22, 23, 24,true); // ESP8266: do not use pin 11

Or change your motor pins using similar logic.